# Is there a possibility to use a bigger List in phython?

Tags: python, pandas

For school I have to make a project about wifisignals and I am trying put the data in a dataframe.
There are 208.000 rows of data.
And when it comes to the code below, the code does not complete. The code is like it is stuck in an infinite loop.
But when I use only a 1000 rows my program works. So I think that my list are to small if that is possible.
Do bigger Lists exist in phython? Or is it because I use bad coding?
Thanks in advance.

edit 1:
(data is the original dataframe and wifiinfo is a column of that)
i have this format:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sender','Time','Date','Place','X','Y','Bezetting','SSID','BSSID','Signal'])
```

And i am trying to fill `SSID`, `BSSID` and `Signal` from the Column `WifiInfo` for this i have to split the data.

this is how 1 WifiInfo looks like:

```py
ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83,ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00:-72,ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-d2-d0:-82,CiscoC5976@58-6d-8f-19-14-38:-78,CiscoC5959@58-6d-8f-19-13-f4:-93,SNB@c8-d7-19-6f-be-b7:-99,ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c5-70:-94,HackingDemo@58-6d-8f-19-11-48:-156,ODISEE@88-1d-fc-30-d4-40:-85,ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-ac-50:-100
```

My current approach looks like:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    bezettingList = list()
    ssidList = list()
    bssidList = list()
    signalList = list()

    #WifiInfo splitting  
    wifis = row.WifiInfo.split(',')
    for wifi in wifis:
        #split wifi and add to List
        ssid, bssid = wifi.split('@')
        bssid, signal = bssid.split(':')
        ssidList.append(ssid)
        bssidList.append(bssid)
        signalList.append(int(signal))

    #add bezettingen to List 
    bezettingen = row.Bezetting.split(',')
    for bezetting in bezettingen:
        bezettingList.append(bezetting) 

    #add list to dataframe
    df.loc[index,'SSID'] = ssidList
    df.loc[index,'BSSID'] = bssidList
    df.loc[index,'Signal'] = signalList
    df.loc[index,'Bezetting'] = bezettingList

df.head()
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing dataframe processing with lists, instead of with pandas itself. It is usually better to use pandas, since pandas aims to use "unboxed" arrays, etc. that reduce the memory footprint significantly, as well as performance.

Comment: At first sight the code is not stuck in an infinite loop. Python's interpreter however usually starts to have problems with processing 100k+ elements, eventually it will process, but it will take considerable time. This is partly due to Pythons very dynamic nature with a lot of fallback mechanisms, that have a certain cost in terms of performance.

Comment: Perhaps it is more useful if you specify *what* you want to do, instead of *how* you want to do it. If you give some sample data (you can provide "made up" data if you do not want to share sensitive data), together with expected output, we can help by providing a more effective solution.

Comment: indeed, you are using plain python lists instead of pandas. But also, I would like you to notice that it's probably not that the code is not completing, but just taking longer. Just expect first that the code with 200k instead of 1k records may take 200 times longer to complete. Are you sure it's not the case? Of course given memory issues it might take even longer, but just for you to realize that.

Comment: Writing to a dataframe with `df.loc[index,'SSID'] = ssidList` is furthermore not very effective as well. Dataframes are tables that are usually good in processing data "in bulk", for individual row editing, these usually end up to be slower.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast reply i will add some extra code to clear everytthing up and it takes also a 'infinite' time with 10k rows.

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: data is a dataframe where i loaded my rows in from my file and wifiInfo is a  column from inside data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to first explode the row by commas so that this:

```py
    SSID    BSSID   Signal  WifiInfo
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83,ODISEE@88- ...
```

becomes this:

```py
    SSID    BSSID   Signal  WifiInfo
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00:-72
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-d2-d0:-82
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     CiscoC5976@58-6d-8f-19-14-38:-78
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     CiscoC5959@58-6d-8f-19-13-f4:-93
5   NaN     NaN     NaN     SNB@c8-d7-19-6f-be-b7:-99
6   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c5-70:-94
7   NaN     NaN     NaN     HackingDemo@58-6d-8f-19-11-48:-156
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-30-d4-40:-85
9   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-ac-50:-100
```

```py
# use `.explode`
data = data.assign(WifiInfo=data.WifiInfo.str.split(',')).explode('WifiInfo')
```

Now you could use `.str.extract`:

```py
data['SSID'] = data['WifiInfo'].str.extract(r'(.*)@')
data['BSSID'] = data['WifiInfo'].str.extract(r'@(.*):')
data['Signal'] = data['WifiInfo'].str.extract(r':(.*)')
```

```py
    SSID        BSSID               Signal  WifiInfo
0   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-41-dc-50   -83     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83
1   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00   -72     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00:-72
2   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-41-d2-d0   -82     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-d2-d0:-82
3   CiscoC5976  58-6d-8f-19-14-38   -78     CiscoC5976@58-6d-8f-19-14-38:-78
4   CiscoC5959  58-6d-8f-19-13-f4   -93     CiscoC5959@58-6d-8f-19-13-f4:-93
5   SNB         c8-d7-19-6f-be-b7   -99     SNB@c8-d7-19-6f-be-b7:-99
6   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-2c-c5-70   -94     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c5-70:-94
7   HackingDemo 58-6d-8f-19-11-48   -156    HackingDemo@58-6d-8f-19-11-48:-156
8   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-30-d4-40   -85     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-30-d4-40:-85
9   ODISEE      88-1d-fc-41-ac-50   -100    ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-ac-50:-100
```

---

If you want to keep data grouped after column explosion, I'd assign an ID for each group of entries first:

```py
data['Group'] = pd.factorize(data['WifiInfo'])[0]+1
```

```py
    SSID    BSSID   Signal  WifiInfo                                     Group 
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83,ODISEE@88- ...  1
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     ASD@22-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83,QWERTY@88-    ...  2
```

```py
# after you explode the column
SSID        BSSID           Signal  WifiInfo                        Group 
ODISEE      88-1d-fc-41-dc-50   -83 ODISEE@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83    1
ODISEE      88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00   -72 ODISEE@88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00:-72    1
...
...
ASD         22-1d-fc-41-dc-50   -83 ASD@88-1d-fc-41-dc-50:-83       2
QWERTY      88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00   -72 QWERTY@88-1d-fc-2c-c0-00:-72    2
```

Comment: or use `data[['SSID', 'BSSID', 'Signal']] = data['WifiInfo'].str.extract(r'(.*)\@(.*)\:(.*)')` to extract everything in one line